# How to programatically download Android apps from google play?

Tags: android, web-crawler, apk

I am trying to obtain a large set of Android apps for analysis purpose and I need the apk files.

Does anyone know how can I download Android apps from Google Play using a program (say a crawler)?

Thanks!

Comment: if such a thing existed. google play's servers would be flooded x times each y seconds. (where x is the highest possible number, and y is the lowest)

Comment: @tony9099 I agree with you. But very few people may need to use such a tool. Like crawlers, I guess web servers will not block such tools as long as they access servers politely (not very frequently).

Answer (score -1):

No but you could manually download all the APK's once and then put these on a server.

After that it is possible to let the program figure out what programs is missing and download these, or just install em all with 'adb install' commands, possibly in a script to automate the process.

Example code to figure out if a PDF viewer is present:

```
public boolean canDisplayPdf() {

    if (getPdfViewersInstalled().size() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public List<String> getPdfViewersInstalled() {
    List<String> viewers = new ArrayList<String>();
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setType(MIME_TYPE_PDF);
    for (ResolveInfo ri : packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)) {
        viewers.add(ri.loadLabel(packageManager).toString());
    }
    return viewers;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a quite old question, but it is useful for new comers. It is indeed possible to build a crawler for the Google Play.

You can start by looking at the [unoficial python API](https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api), I wrote a [simple script](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/aknahs/qekgd) based on this API that downloads the top 50 most popular apps which i [explain in detail](http://www.marioalmeida.eu/2017/03/01/700/).

Also take a look at [PlayDrone](https://github.com/nviennot/playdrone), an opensource platform for doing just that, crawling the Google Play market. Or if you don't need fresh apps, you can retrieve their [apps database from archive.](https://archive.org/details/android_apps&tab=about)